# How to automating the process of creating logstash configuration file

Tags: logstash

I want to ask that,
how to automating the process of creating logstash configuration file ? I mean that creating a script that generates configuration files. I mean, giving grok patterns from console etc, that auto generate the configuration files. Can someone give an example ?
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of function, you have 2 options :

- *Hard* : [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html), looks this [role](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-logstash) to look how to use it to deploy logstash configuration file. This option is hard, because you need to learn the basic usage of ansible, but this is not a waste of time.
- *Easy* : basic [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) template, this option is more easy because the jinja template is just a part of ansible, so it's more easy to use it and learn.

Comment: I have checked => https://fabianlee.org/2016/10/31/python-using-python-json-and-jinja2-to-construct-a-set-of-logstash-filters/. I want to ask that when running normal logstash conf, i use logstash -f  path_to_conf, how should i start logstash with jinja, when running py script, is logstash instance starting ?

Comment: The point is not to use logstash with jinja, but just use jinja to manage the configuration file. After this generation step, start logstash as usual.